# What's the remainder when $100!+5400$ is divided by $124$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm pretty much stuck on this one because of the factorial.
In this case, how can I solve it?

Comment: $124=2^2\times 31.$

Comment: 124 is a divisor of 100! (prove why yourself) so its remainder  is 0 , the rest you know, good luck

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** $100!$ is a multiple of $124$.  How do we know?  What does this tell us?